# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute for a python method

Tags: python-2.7, pydev, python-unittest

I have recently installed QuantLib-Python on Ubuntu 16.04 via apt:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libquantlib0-dev libquantlib0v5 quantlib-python
```

It seems thats when I call QuantLib via a **unittest** on Eclipse PyDev I  get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Date'
```

However, I can successfully execute QuantLib via the **terminal** or as a regular **Python-script** from Eclipse or as a **Pytest** from Eclipse. See sample code below:

```
>>> import QuantLib as ql
>>> print ( ql.Date(1,1,2010) )
January 1st, 2010
```

The QuantLib shared library is installed in the following folder:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/QuantLib/
init.py init.pyc QuantLib.py QuantLib.pyc _QuantLib.so
```

The QuantLib folder is included in my `sys.path`, both on Eclipse and on Terminal. The output is given below:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Mako-1.0.7-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MarkupSafe-1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/appdirs-1.4.3-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Oracle-6.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/decorator-4.1.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py-1.4.34-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycuda-2017.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest-3.1.3-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytools-2017.4-py2.7.egg
```

***Does anyone know why the QuantLib module fails via the unittest framework?***

PS: This post was modified, after I have found out that it fails only via unittest.

Comment: May I see the output of `import sys; print(sys.path)`.

Comment: @stovfl thank you for the response I was just testing this actually :)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py-1.4.34-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycuda-2017.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest-3.1.3-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytools-2017.4-py2.7.egg

Comment: You are missing `'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'` in Eclipse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152388/discussion-between-user1221647-and-stovfl).

Answer (score 0):

The unittest fixture apparently was written in the following file **QuantLib.py** (This was the mistake!!!), while my naming convention is TestNamesomething and the PyTest was written in the right way. Obviously, this was confusing the interpreter and eventually it was the last thing I have noticed. I changed the unitest file to something else than QuantLib.py and it is all back to normal. The test results are given below:

```
import unittest
import QuantLib as ql

class QuantLibFixture(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dates(self):
        date1 = ql.Date(1,12,2017)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

the unittest error before the file correction:

```
>>> python QuantLib.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_dates (__main__.QuantLibFixture)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "QuantLib.py", line 12, in test_dates
    date1 = ql.Date(1,12,2017)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Date'
FAILED (errors=1)
```

the unittest run after the correction:

```
test_dates (tests.PyLib.Adhoc.TestQuantLib.QuantLibFixture) ... ok
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
OK
```